# Computing ideal intersections in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose, $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $I,J,A,B,C,D$ are ideals in $R$. Suppose, I can write $A,B,C,D$ explicitly in terms of generators and I can also compute $A\cap B$ explicitly in terms of generators. It is also known,

$I=A+C$

$J=B+D$

How would I go about computing $I\cap J$, if this can be done at all.

To clarify what I mean by explicitly, I can write an ideal as $(f_1,...,f_n)$, where the polynomials $f_i$ are not specified, but I know certain properties of these (so I can write down examples). So, I would like to write down $I\cap J$ in terms of the generators of $A,B,C,D,A\cap B$.

Comment: I don't see how you could do this without also being able to compute at least the generators of $C\cap D$. For instance, if the variables in the generators of $A$ and $B$ are disjoint from the variables in the generators of $C$ and $D$, wouldn't the generators of $I\cap J$ have to include the generators of $C\cap D$?

Answer (score 2):

Look up [Gröbner bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis). Algorithms based on them are implemented in most symbolic algebra programs. Try for instance [Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/).

Comment: I have used Macaulay2 and Macsyma before. This is NOT what I am looking for. I am looking for an abstract expression for the intersection ideal and not for specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for, but for any ideals $I,J\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ you may write
\begin{align*}
 I\cap J = (tI + (1-t)J) \cap k[x_1,\ldots,x_n],
\end{align*}
where $t\in K[t]$ is a variable, and the notation $tS$ for any ideal $S$ means $\{tf:f\in S\}$.

If you have access to Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'Shea, it's Theorem 11 in section 4.3 (page 187-188 if you get it on google books.)